# How do you open a new tab in Selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide

I am beginner automation tester.  Currently using Selenium IDE and I am trying to open a page in a new browser tab.  Used the following commands:

(1) Click 
(2) WaitForPopUp
(3) Select Popup
(4) VerifyText
(5) Close
(6) SelectWindow

The object that is being clicked is an image with a link and when clicked, it is supposed to open a new page in a separate tab.  Browser being used is FireFox.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: What is your problem? When clicked, new tabs does open and you cannot switch to it? Or tab does not open? Also, new test will get new FF profile, which might have popups disabled by default.

Comment: New Tab opens, but, I can not get to it. I've used the above commands before, but, for some reason on this particular image link  the commands are not working.

Comment: treat as a new window and use switchTo http://stackoverflow.com/a/9597714/631619

Answer (score 2):

Example URL: `http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET_95y98y108y97y110y107y.html`

Example Element: `<a href="newwindow.html" target="_blank">a new window</a>`

**Solution in IDE**

1. Enter `http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/` as your Base URL
2. Click the record button

   - Navigate to `http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET_95y98y108y97y110y107y.html`
   - Left-click the a new window link
   - Right-click on the page and select verifyTitle A Whole New Window – HTML Code Tutorial
   - Close the new window/tab
   - Right-click on the original window/tab page and select verifyTitle HTML _blank – HTML Code Tutorial
3. In Selenium IDE, click the record button to stop recording
4. Add a `pause` `1000` step after the click step to give the window/tab time to load
5. Add a `selectWindow` `A Whole New Window – HTML Code Tutorial` step after the pause to connect to the new window/tab
6. Add a `close` step after the `verifyTitle` `A Whole New Window – HTML Code Tutorial step`
7. Add a `selectWindow` `HTML _blank – HTML Code Tutorial` step after the close step
8. Select Play Current Test Case to verify the test

Answer (score 1):

I'm using IDE commands to open a new window (not a panel), to do something in a different application.

Essential is to select window according to the window label (title) and closing the window and selecting null after it is finished.

Hope this will help. Example of opening a page, which I'm using to get swift data of random bank:

```
<tr>
    <td>openWindow</td>
    <td>https://transferwise.com/swift-codes/countries</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>title=Search Swift / BIC codes by country - TransferWise</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//div[@id=&quot;country-Z&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

...

```
<tr>
    <td>close</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```